# CSS Radio-button and text outline

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with setting up box & shadow around my radio button. My CSS sets box only around radio button and shows nasty white square box around it. How to set border or outline around whole Radio-button + text to make selection more distinctive.

```css
enrgy-form {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.label-width {
  margin-left: 22px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.label-nowrapp {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.selected-item input:checked {
  /*border: 1px solid dodgerblue;*/
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 11px 1px dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check enrgy-form">
  <label class="form-check-label label-nowrapp selected-item">
                <input class="form-check-input selected-item" type="radio" name="energy" formControlName="energy" value="Energy" (change)="setOptions()">Fuel-fired</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @j08691Unfortunatly your solution doesn't fix the problem when you run code snippet it looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to simulate the radio button with css so you can have the behavior you want.

You should first set the input to `display: none` and give it an `id` in your HTML so you can link it with the label, by giving the label a `for` attribute, this way you can control the check/uncheck of your radio button from the label.

Next you want to simulate the appearance of the radio button, i'll do this by adding two spans, one inside the other, so we can have a checked/unchecked status.

try this:

```css
enrgy-form {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.label-width {
  margin-left: 22px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.label-nowrapp {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.selected-item {
  display: none;
}

.selected-item:checked + label {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 2px dodgerblue;
}
label{
  padding: 3px;
}

label .bullet{
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-right: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.selected-item:checked + label .bullet .bullet-selected{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check enrgy-form">
  <input class="form-check-input selected-item" type="radio" name="energy" formControlName="energy" value="Energy" (change)="setOptions()" id="someUniqueId"/>
  <label class="form-check-label label-nowrapp" for="someUniqueId">
     <span class="bullet">
      <span class="bullet-selected"></span>
     </span>
     Fuel-fired
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go the route where you style the whole radio button using `:before` and `:after` in CSS. That way you could even go nuts with animations and stuff...

It would require you to change the HTML  a bit as well.... 
There's plenty of examples to be found if you search for "css custom radio".

```css
[type="radio"]{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

[type="radio"] + label
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


[type="radio"] + label:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:before{
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 11px 1px dodgerblue;
}

[type="radio"] + label:after{
    content: '';
    display: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}


[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check enrgy-form">
  
    <input type="radio" name="energy" id="one">
    <label for="one">Fuel-fired</label>
    </input>

    <input type="radio" name="energy" id="two">
    <label for="two">Something else</label>
    </input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update

Here is a possible solution, you could modify it as you want!

```css
.form-check {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.form-check-label {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.form-check-input {
 margin: 0;
 margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.form-check-input:checked + .form-check-label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1.5em 8px 8px 1.5em;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 11px 1px dodgerblue;
}

.medium { font-size: 2rem; }
.medium input[type=radio] { zoom: 2 }

.big { font-size: 3rem; }
.big input[type=radio] { zoom: 3 }
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input id="inputcheck" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="energy" formControlName="energy" value="Energy">
  <label for="inputcheck" class="form-check-label">Fuel-fired normal</label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="form-check medium">
  <input id="inputcheck1" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="energy" formControlName="energy" value="Energy">
  <label for="inputcheck1" class="form-check-label">Fuel-fired medium</label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="form-check big">
  <input id="inputcheck2" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="energy" formControlName="energy" value="Energy">
  <label for="inputcheck2" class="form-check-label">Fuel-fired big</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not the original asker (nor the downvoter) but that doesn't appear to solve the problem.

Comment: @DBS I improve it according to the answer, thank you for your advice :)